# Qt c++ strange behavior

Tags: c++, qt, nullpointerexception

This code is not working in our constructor method, it is only working in a slot method. If we try to compile this code in constructor we get null pointer exception in Qt. But the same piece of code is working fine if we put it in other method (same class):

```
for(int l=0; l<sizeof(evo_ws); l++){

  printf("%d\n", evo_ws[l].generationen);
  printf("hulla");

}
```

Comment: You don't even say what is `evo_ws`. Have you checked it's not actually null ?

Comment: we defined a slot für a pushbutton with exactly the sae piece of code, there it is working fine

Comment: extern EVO_WS_TYPE   *evo_ws;     is extern var

Comment: EVO_WS_TYPE is typedef struct

Comment: @Nildse And where is this `extern` variable actually pointing to a valid instance?  I believe you have just mismanaged or misused your pointer, and the programs where it "works" is just undefined behavior kicking in.  The answer below already shows that your usage of `sizeof` is totally wrong, so it won't be surprising if you have done other things wrong in your program.

Comment: if we try to debug we get SIGSEGV Segmentation fault....

Comment: You didn't answer the basic question: *Where does the pointer evo_ws get initialized?*  You don't need a debugger for that -- it's your code and you must have had it initialized somewhere.  Right now, being `extern` means that the pointer is NULL.

Comment: this var is initialized in other header file extern EVO_WS_TYPE   *evo_ws;

Comment: we include this header file in our class

Comment: even this code is not working for(int l=0; l<3; l++){

  printf("%d\n", evo_ws[0].generationen);
  

}

Comment: is this the right way to access the integer var of this struct pointer ?

Comment: @Nildse Please show *how* this variable is initialized -- don't describe it.  Show the code.  Also, do you know what I mean by "initialized"?  You have a pointer, *but what does it point to?*  Just declaring a pointer isn't enough -- you have to point it somewhere before you use it.  That's what is missing from you -- where/when/how do you point this pointer to a *valid* instance of your struct?

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns size in bytes. I expect that `evo_ws` is declared such as `Type evo_ws[20];`. In that case `sizeof(evo_ws)` can be more than 20. You should use `sizeof(evo_ws)/sizeof(*evo_ws)`.

Comment: we also tried                                             for(int l=0;l<3;l++){

        printf("%d\n",evo_ws[l].generationen);
        printf("hulla");

    }

Comment: this code is workig fine in oter methode, only not working in contructor method

Comment: `printf` is working fine in Qt. Is `evo_ws` really declared as a fixed-size array? Or is it a pointer? Or something else?

Comment: @Nildse Have you determined it is a `printf` problem?  How about just a simple `printf("abc\n");` and remove that line that uses the mysterious `evo_ws`?

Comment: In that case, the pointer seems to be `nullptr` in the constructor and is initialized later. Also if it is a pointer, `sizeof` does not return size of the pointed array but size of the pointer itself (4 bytes for 32-bit, 8 bytes for 64-bit systems).